# What should I do if I block other people but I supposed to work on the project only 20% of my time?

Tags: software-industry, work-time

I am assigned to two projects. I was told to spend 80% of my time on the first one and 20% on the second one.

The problem is that the second project is legacy code and currently it doesn't work and I'm the only one on the project who can solve this. The project has a lot of bugs which completely block QA and fronted engineers and these bugs required days of debug. I don't have the time because the first project is also requires a lot of work but I have no problems with this one because I can spent enough time on tasks.

What should I do? I don't want to overtime but I also feel uncomfortable because other members of my team can't do their job because of me.

Comment: Speak to your manager or whomever told you to split your time that way.

Comment: Not because you *you*.  It is because of the priorities that have been assigned to you.  I don't get the VTC.  I think this is a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already know what to do - **spend 80% on A and 20% on B.** Do that until you're told otherwise.

If you are a bottleneck (your low allocation on B is preventing other people from doing their jobs), let your manager know, and give some specific examples of when that has been the case. Also explain how you could solve some of the issues with the project and explain how much time it would take.

Make sure you indicate that **you understand your current allocation, but you are asking for a (potentially short term) change in allocation** to solve some of these major issues.

Priorities and allocations are important tools for managing workload, but if there is a bottleneck that management doesn't have visibility into, that feedback can be useful.